# how to get a pointer pointing at centre of slider thumb? CSS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

I have a feature to show the price range and the most repeated price (Mode). What i did is i used the range input type and deactivated it (so it can't be moved by user as it's only for illustration).

Below is my HTML, CSS and JS which i guess will explain better my issue

```
<div class="range">
    <div class="sliderValue">
        <span class="show" style="left: ${pinPostion}%;">${mostCommonMaxPrice}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="value left">${lowestMinPrice}</div>
        <input type="range" min="${lowestMinPrice}" max="${highestMaxPrice}" value="${mostCommonMaxPrice}" disabled>
        <div class="value right">${highestMaxPrice}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.range{
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 32.5px 0 22.5px;
}
.field{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.field .value{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4638D2;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.field .value.left{
  left: -15px;
}
.field .value.right{
  right: -21.5px;
}
.range input{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2222;
}
.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #4638D2 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4638D2;
  border: 1px solid #4638D2;
}
 
.range input::-moz-range-progress{
  background: #4638D2;
}
.sliderValue{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.sliderValue span{
  font-size: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 22.5px;
  width: 22.5px;
  /*transform: translateX(-70%) scale(0);*/
  font-weight: 600;
  top: -15px;
  line-height: 27.5px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.sliderValue span.show{
  transform: translateX(-70%) scale(1.3);
}
.sliderValue span:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4638D2;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```
const pinPostion = (((mostCommonMaxPrice - lowestMinPrice)/(highestMaxPrice - lowestMinPrice)) * 100) + lowestMinPrice;
```

[image: Price range sliders]

[image]

As you see in the picture am not able to get the bubble that shows the mode number to point at the slider thumb position, it is only showing well when it's 100 but if it's more or less then it goes off position, I tried to calculate the percentage and pass it as a variable but it's still coming off, am not sure if my CSS is wrong or is it the equation am using or am I doing all this altogether wrong and there is an easier way to do it. I really appreciate your help. And would be grateful if you up the question, please :)

Comment: Could you make your code into a snippet we can run? It makes it much easier to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At first glance it looks as though some calculation is missing the (rotated) border.

Comment: @AHaworth thank you for providing the link, I always wondered how posts get the run snippet button and the link you provided explained it. I see that Mr. Brickowski did it for me already in his comment below. He also mentioned the border but i really didn't get it and didn't know which CSS line would fix that, would be grateful if you take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some code example here, it uses similar to yours approach with manual position calculation for Value Bubble, try it:

```js
const allRanges = document.querySelectorAll(".range-wrap");
allRanges.forEach(wrap => {
  const range = wrap.querySelector(".range");
  const bubble = wrap.querySelector(".bubble");

  range.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setBubble(range, bubble);
  });
  setBubble(range, bubble);
});

function setBubble(range, bubble) {
  const val = range.value;
  const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
  const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
  const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 100) / (max - min));
  bubble.innerHTML = val;

  // Sorta magic numbers based on size of the native UI thumb
  bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${8 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
}
```

```css
.range-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 3rem;
}
.range {
  width: 100%;
}
.bubble {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  top: -1px;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap">
  <input type="range" class="range">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>

<div class="range-wrap">
  <input type="range" class="range" min="20" max="940">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>

<div class="range-wrap" style="width: 75%;">
  <input type="range" class="range" min="50" max="60" step="2">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>

<div class="range-wrap" style="width: 55%;">
  <input type="range" class="range" min="-20" max="20">
  <output class="bubble"></output>
</div>
```

I found it here https://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/

Comment: Thank you this can be very helpful I will try it out if the one I had can't be made better, so i will just change it to the one you provided

Comment: I implemented the calc() line into my code and did a bit of adjustments to the equation as i changes the native UI size of the thumb and it worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the pinpoint position does not consider the border width of the pinpoint itself, therefore it is not aligned to its center of the tip.

Consider this example, the pinpoint should be right at the middle:

| variable | value |
| --- | --- |
| lowestMinPrice | 0 |
| highestMaxPrice | 100 |
| mostCommonMaxPrice | 50 |

```
const pinPostion = (((mostCommonMaxPrice - lowestMinPrice)/(highestMaxPrice - lowestMinPrice)) * 100) + lowestMinPrice;
pinPostion = (((50 - 0)/(100 - 0)) * 100) + 0;
pinPostion = 50
```

The pinpoint is made from a rotated element with border radius. If I take the radius off, this is how it looks

[image]

If I further take the transform off, this is how it looks

[image]

Even I port the number to your example, the pinpoint is off a little bit.

```css
.range {
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 32.5px 0 22.5px;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.field .value {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #4638D2;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.field .value.left {
  left: -15px;
}

.field .value.right {
  right: -21.5px;
}

.range input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2222;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #4638D2 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4638D2;
  border: 1px solid #4638D2;
}

.range input::-moz-range-progress {
  background: #4638D2;
}

.sliderValue {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.sliderValue span {
  font-size: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 22.5px;
  width: 22.5px;
  /*transform: translateX(-70%) scale(0);*/
  font-weight: 600;
  top: -15px;
  line-height: 27.5px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.sliderValue span.show {
  transform: translateX(-70%) scale(1.3);
}

.sliderValue span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4638D2;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <div class="sliderValue">
    <span class="show" style="left: 50%;">50</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="value left">0</div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" disabled>
    <div class="value right">100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and thank you for making my code to be able to be run as a snippet I didn't know how to do that. I understood what you meant about the width is that issue, but honestly i could not resolve it, I think i need some CSS course :D, can you please provide me with the CSS fix? Thanks

Comment: @MustafaAl-Ani May I change the DOM structure?

Comment: I literally just solved it....what i did is used the calc() function that @true_k gave in his answer but manipulated it a bit as i changed the thumb size of the slider and it worked perfectly....thank you very much for the help :) i really appreciate it :)